# Regex check for specific phone phone numbers or extensions

Tags: regex

String to be evaluated will be either be a 10 digit number or a 4 digit number.

```
5551119900 (10 Digit)
9999 (4 Digit)
```

Need regex to test for specific list of 10 digit numbers or 4 digit numbers. I have the following Regex that almost works

```
55511199(00|01|02|10|20|30)|(0000|9901|9902|9903|9999)
```

Above is checking for

```
5551119900
5551119901
5551119902
5551119910
5551119920
5551119930
0000
9901
9902
9903
9999
```

ISSUE:

(1) Need match to be exactly 10 digits or 4 digits only.

(2) Pattern match (see link below) is showing an exact match and also a "Group 1". I'm not sure what the group match means or if that is a good thing.

Sample: https://regex101.com/r/BbplFG/1/

Comment: (1) surround with word delimiters (eg. `\b`); (2) a group is a portion of the match that you can access and use elsewhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this version of your regex:

```
^(?:55511199(?:00|01|02|10|20|30)|(?:0000|9901|9902|9903|9999))$
```

### Demo

I have made several changes here:

- Used `?:` inside terms in parentheses, to turn off group capturing
- Placed the entire pattern inside parentheses
- Added starting (`^`) and ending (`$`) anchors around the entire pattern